# Find closest value

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing an issue in my project. I have a list of product name like

> 'Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Chocolate Mint 2.07 lbs'
>
> 'Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard (Natural) Vanilla 1.9 lbs'
>
> 'Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Chocolate Mint 2.07 lbs'
>
> 'Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Chocolate Peanut Butter 3.31 lbs'
>
> 'Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Key Lime Pie 1.81 lbs'
>
> 'Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Salted Caramel 1.81 lbs'
>
> 'Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Vanilla Ice Cream 2.07 lbs'

All these product save in the product table

and then I have another table that store the size category.

> "1 lbs, 3.3 lbs, 8 lbs, 1.8 lbs, 3 lbs, 10 lbs, 5 lbs, 2 Lbs, 2.91 Lbs, 2.47 Lbs, 2.5 Lbs".

I am categorizing the product so that if size found inside the **product name** then the product will be assign to that size category.

For example

> "Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Double Rich Chocolate 1 lbs"

In this product we have size 1 lbs and 1 lbs also exists in our size category table, then product will be assign to 1 lbs category.

I am using following regular expression for this:

```
preg_match("/[\s]+\b$size\b/", $product_name) OR
preg_match("/[\-]+\b$size\b/", $product_name) OR   
preg_match("/\b$size\b/", $product_name)
```

Where `$size` is the size that I am getting from size category table and `$product_name` is the name of the products and its currently working fine for me.

Now I want if a particular size available in product, but not exists in size category table, then that product should assign to the closest size category.

For example

> Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Chocolate Mint 2.07 lbs'

2.07 Lbs is not exists in my size category table then this product should assign to 2 Lbs or 2.47 Lbs category.

Comment: Lets first see your regular expression that extracts the mass and then we can build upon that

Comment: @rohit kaushal Any idea how you can build your regex? Did you learn about PCRE yet?

Comment: Show us your attempt SQL queries to obtain the smaller and bigger size from your database.

Comment: Nice 2lbs of chocolate mint!

Comment: Well, you'll have to find the current size from the feed ( regx ) and then use a range >= and <= on your size table.

Comment: Pearl Compatible Regular Expression, PCRE or regex will allow you to extract `2.07` from your product name string.

Comment: This is my current regular expression preg_match("/[\s]+\b$serv_nameA\b/", $p_nameA) OR preg_match("/[\-]+\b$serv_nameA\b/", $p_nameA) OR preg_match("/\b$serv_nameA\b/", $p_nameA) Where $serv_nameA is the size that I am getting from size table and $p_nameA is the name of the product.

Comment: OK, is the regular expression providing the results you need? Could you test it? What is your next problem?

Comment: I think you need more a regex that matches the `2.07 lbs` like `\s(2.07)\slbs` where I let you match `2.07` in a generic and robust way. You can test it at https://regex101.com/ Then extract the 2.07 and query the database.

Comment: This regular expression working fine for me, if I have a size available in my size table.
But I want a solution when size don't have, then the product automatically assign to its closest size.
For example if I don't have size 2.07 lbs in my size table the product automatically assign to 2 lbs that exist in my table.

Comment: I understand that. I think you should work like this. Step 1: Find `2.07` with a regex. Step 2: Find first value lower than `2.07` and first value higher than `2.07` in your database. E.g. `2.00` and `2.10`. Step 3: Determine which value is closest. E.g. `2.10`

Comment: Good programmer's practice is to use variable names that make sense to the readers. `$serv_nameA` and `$p_nameA` don't make sens to me. They don't help me to understand what they mean or contain.

Comment: I edit my question in proper format.

Answer (score 0):

If your database contains 2.00 and 2.10 then for
Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Chocolate Mint 2.07 lbs

## Step 1: Regex: Find 2.07

You need a regex that matches the `2.07 lbs` like

```
$haystack = 'Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Chocolate Mint 2.07 lbs';
preg_match('/(07)\slbs/', $haystack, $matches); // you still have to do some howework here
print_r($matches);
```

I let you match 2.07 in a generic and robust way. You can test your regex at http://regex101.com or http://www.phpliveregex.com/

## Step 2: SQL:

- Find first value lower than 2.07 and
- Find first value higher than 2.07 in your database.
  E.g. 2.00 and 2.10.

## Step 3: PHP: Determine which value is closest.

E.g. 2.10

Comment: How would we achieve step one, as if the product name is Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Chocolate Mint 2.07 lbs.
How can we find 2.07 lbs is the size ? 
I usually find it by regular expression if I have the size already exist in my size table.

Comment: I don't think so its a right approach. Size would be variate, for example, lbs, serving, tablet, bottles etc and each time the value of the size can be different in the particular product, like some time it will be 2.07 lbs and some time 2.07lbs (no spacing). Some time 1.5, 2.04, 3.33. What should be the dynamic approach for this.

Comment: Challenging. I'm not shure this can be solved. Going further requires many more examples of the possible values of both your separate table and your product names. Please add them to your question.

Comment: For example I have an array for size like this 
$arr_size = array(1 lbs, 3.3 lbs, 8 lbs, 2.3 lbs, 3 lbs, 10 lbs, 5 lbs ); and product name like:
array('Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein Vanilla 1.9 lbs', 'Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard 2.07 lbs','Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Chocolate Peanut Butter 3.31 lbs',' Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Key Lime Pie 1.81 lbs',' Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Salted Caramel 1.81 lbs','Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard Vanilla Ice Cream 2.07 lbs');

Comment: @rohitkaushal Where is that array coming from. In the question, it is called a table. Is that a database table?

Comment: @rohitkaushal Can you edit your question and put the details there, nicely formatted. The comment is difficult to read.

Comment: We can help you, when something does not work, but not write the program for you. The examples provided do not contain `lbs, serving, tablet, bottles` that you said would be an issue and I asked details for. Also, your regex do not take into account the case sensitivity of `lbs` and `Lbs` in the array. I still don't know it the table is a database... Even if we program it for you, there is a big risk of additional requirements. It is taking to much time. Sorry, I give up.

Answer (score -1):

```
$search_product='2.07 Lbs';
$available_products=array('2 Lbs','2.91 Lbs','2.47 Lbs','2.5 Lbs');

for($i=0;$i<count($available_products);$i++){   
    if(!isset($closet_value)){
        $closet_diff=abs($search_product-$available_products[$i]);
        $closet_value=$available_products[$i];
    }else if($closet_diff>abs($search_product-$available_products[$i])){
        $closet_diff=abs($search_product-$available_products[$i]);
        $closet_value=$available_products[$i];
    }

}
echo $closet_value;
```

2 Lbs

Comment: This solution is not giving me any result.
$search_product='2.07 Lbs'; should be a name of the product, not a size itself.
Like 
$search_product = 'Optimum Nutrition 100 Whey Protein - Gold Standard (Natural) Vanilla 1.9 lbs'

Comment: The Main thing is that you don't have proper database format.

Kindly categorize your product into Product Name,Category,Description and Size.